# CryptoJS decode PHP

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptojs

It can be decoded with the code below, but I want to do this in PHP. How can I do it?

There is a PHP class, but it requires information like iv, I don't know how to decode

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt("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","U2FsdGVkX1/FhXfmnDLMdW/zwst2X9dIxPuBfc876cs=");
document.write(bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
</script>
```

Comment: As the PHP/openssl decrypt function has an error detection we cannot test any decryption with a crippeled ciphertext. Kindly edit your question and post the **complete** ciphertext (or use & append another - shorter - plaintext for encryption), thanks.

The good news is: there is high chance that decryption in PHP is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `CryptoJS.decrypt()`, if the 2nd parameter is passed as a string, [CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input) uses the OpenSSL function [`EVP_BytesToKey`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html) as a key derivation function to derive a 32 bytes key and a 16 bytes IV.

For decryption, this derivation function must also be used in PHP. There are several (mostly simplified) implementations on the Net for PHP, such as [here](https://gist.github.com/ezimuel/67fa19030c75052b0dde278a383eda1b), where CryptoJS uses MD5 instead of SHA256.

When encrypting, `CryptoJS.encrypt()` generates an 8 bytes salt that is contained in the second half of the first block (bytes 8 to 16), the first half corresponds to the ASCII encoded value of `Salted__`. This salt must also be determined.

A possible PHP implementation could be:

```
// from: https://gist.github.com/ezimuel/67fa19030c75052b0dde278a383eda1b
function EVP_BytesToKey($salt, $password) {
    $bytes = "";
    $last = "";

    // 32 bytes key + 16 bytes IV = 48 bytes.
    while(strlen($bytes) < 48) {
        $last = hash('md5', $last . $password . $salt, true);
        $bytes.= $last;
    }
    return $bytes;
}      
       
$dataB64 = "U2FsdGVkX1...";

// Separate salt and ciphertext
$data = base64_decode($dataB64);
$salt = substr($data,8,8);
$ciphertext = substr($data,16);

// Determine key and IV
$passphrase = "U2FsdGVkX1/FhXfmnDLMdW/zwst2X9dIxPuBfc876cs=";
$keyiv = EVP_BytesToKey($salt, $passphrase);
$key = substr($keyiv, 0, 32);
$iv = substr($keyiv, 32, 16);

// Decrypt
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, "aes-256-cbc", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
print($decrypted);
```

which successfully decrypts the ciphertext.

Note that the proprietary `EVP_BytesToKey` is considered [insecure](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29139) and it is better to use a standard such as PBKDF2 for key derivation.